# Add on creating in ADD menu

Tags: python

I started making an add on to blender but i would like to be able to access it from add menu. I only find the way to put it in the side panel what pops up with ‘N’.

Tried to put for “location”: View3D > Add > but no luck

Thank you

Comment: does this work? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/how-to-add-a-custom-object-entry-to-the-add-menu

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui

Comment: I want to use my add on from ADD menu. So when i press shift+A i would have my add on in the menu.

Comment: Just seen the first comment. And yes it helps. This is what i want to achieve. I’m making materials and meshes. New to pyton but will look into it. 
Thank you for the help