# Scripting Addon That Appends Rig

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to program an addon that adds a new option when pressing Shift+A that adds a rig. I have the .blend file of the rig, so how can I write a script to append the rig into the scene?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/how-to-add-a-custom-object-entry-to-the-add-menu https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui